# I cannot retrieve SharedPreference value created in native code from Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have code that creates a shared preference on the native side.
When I add a value to it, I can not get it from my Dart code.
Only after I restart the app or recompile, I can access the value.

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you use the [`shared_preferences` package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), which [caches the shared preferences internally](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart).
You can call `reload()` on your shared preferences instance to fetch the latest values from the host platform:

```dart
var sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await sharedPrefs.reload();
// sharedPrefs now contains the latest entries
```